# How to disable Visual Studio 2017 from indexing files

Tags: visual-studio

I'm new to VS and noticed that when I cloned one of my repos it started to index it. It's stuck at 26% and won't continue, and it causes VS to run very slow. Is there a setting somewhere that I have to disable? Thanks.